# Automate drag drop with windows api

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I'm want to automate dragging a file onto an external application. I want to do this by sending a message to the target application rather than trying something error prone, like moving the mouse.

As a test case, I'm trying to do this with notepad.exe. I'm running this test code in anaconda as the administrator, but it fails on `VirtualProtectEx` with error code 87. Which seems to mean an invalid parameter, but I'm totally lost as to what's invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
import ctypes
import struct
import win32con
import win32process
import win32gui

GetWindowThreadProcessId = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId
VirtualAllocEx = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAllocEx
VirtualFreeEx = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualFreeEx
OpenProcess = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
WriteProcessMemory = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory
ReadProcessMemory = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory

VirtualProtectEx = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualProtectEx
VirtualProtectEx.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID]
VirtualProtectEx.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL


def dragFileToWnd(filename, hwnd):
    # Pack the data
    filepath = bytes(filename + "\0\0", encoding="GBK")
    packed_filedata = struct.pack("iiiii" + str(len(filepath)) + "s",*[0x14, 0x0A, 0x0A, 00, 00, filepath])  
    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(packed_filedata)

    # Find window handles for the specific thread
    thread_id, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    pid = ctypes.c_uint(pid)

    # Attach to process
    hProcHnd = OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
    
    # Allocate memory in target process
    mem_addr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcHnd, 0, len(buffer), win32con.MEM_RESERVE|win32con.MEM_COMMIT, win32con.PAGE_READWRITE)

    # Apply for protected memory access?
    # WriteProcessMemory returns a 998 error, that I *think* VirtualProtectEx
    # will fix, but VirtualProtectEx returns error 87.
    oldprotect = ctypes.c_ulong()
    protect_result = VirtualProtectEx(hProcHnd, mem_addr, len(buffer), win32con.PAGE_READWRITE, ctypes.byref(oldprotect))
    if not protect_result:
        print('VirtualProtectEx Failed with error code', ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcHnd, mem_addr, 0, win32con.MEM_RELEASE)
        return

    # Write filenames to target process
    # As I understand it, we must write our filenames in the target processes' memory
    # or the drop will fail / memory address won't be vaild.
    bytes_written = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcHnd, mem_addr, buffer, len(buffer), ctypes.byref(bytes_written))

    # Restore memory access
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcHnd, mem_addr, len(buffer), oldprotect.value, ctypes.byref(oldprotect))

    # Send ancient drag-drop message from windows 3.1 era, and hope the application accepts it
    # Is there a better way? That doesn't involve injecting memory?
    print("Bytes bytes_written:", bytes_written.value)
    if bytes_written.value > 0:
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_DROPFILES, mem_addr)
    else:
        print('Drop failed with error code', ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
    
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcHnd, mem_addr, 0, win32con.MEM_RELEASE)

# Test it while an empty notepad is open
filepath = f"{os.environ['userprofile']}\Desktop\log.txt"
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad")
dragFileToWnd(filepath, hwnd)
```

```
VirtualProtectEx Failed with error code 87
```

Comment: What if the application implements drag drop with a different API? Then your code is destined never to work.

Comment: I'm targeting a specific app, and I don't know if this will work until I get past this error code. My understanding is that I should probably be using the windows OLE api's, but I haven't found examples for doing this with OLE.

Comment: You should use UI Automation for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/ui-automation-support-for-drag-and-drop

Comment: You are not validating that `OpenProcess()` is successful before manipulating memory in the target process. For instance, `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is way too much permission to ask for, you only need `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` and `PROCESS_VM_WRITE`. That said, there is no need to use `VirtualProtectEx()` in this code at all.  You are allocating the memory as read/write to begin with, so why are you trying to change its protection to read/write?